# systemctl --user takes tens of seconds to run

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd

I have an intermittent problem on one of my servers where it takes up to ~15 seconds to login. This is over ssh as my own user, not as root.

Also, once I've logged in, sometimes "sudo su" takes ~tens of seconds.

Finally, I just noticed that I can reproduce the issue on demand by running "systemctl --user" as my user (not as root).

I can see the systemd process spiking to 100% CPU when this happens.

```
# in htop
    PID USER       PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S  CPU%▽MEM%   TIME+  Command
 206136 todd        20   0 53680 46120  8656 R  99.0  1.2  6h10:06 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

I can watch the process in `strace`, but nothing is really standing out to me, or seems to correlate with the hangup / resume. I do see a lot of these, so perhaps it's reallocating / rearranging some data structures?

```
brk(0x5607dc128000)                     = 0x5607dc128000
brk(0x5607dc149000)                     = 0x5607dc149000
```

Also, sometimes it doesn't complete, and times out

```
0 %  [via 192.168.99.8] systemctl --user
Failed to list units: Connection timed out
```

Any ideas what I can do to debug / identify the issue?

```
1 %  [via 192.168.99.8] uname -a
Linux bifrost 5.19.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue, 20 Sep 2022 15:17:59 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

0 %  [via 192.168.99.8] pacman -Q systemd
systemd 251.4-1
```

One other detail - as I've been seeing this off and on for months - I know that if I reboot the machine, the issue doesn't recur for a few days.

EDIT: with `strace -r` to show relative timestamps, it seems I've found the culprit.

```
     0.000128 getrandom("\xeb\x49\xb5\x3d\x37\x5a\xc4\xd6\x59\x2e\x5c\x5c\x8a\x5a\x35\xfd", 16, GRND_INSECURE) = 16
     0.000141 getrandom("\x04\xa7\xa1\xa9\xe4\xbb\x5c\x2c\xa3\x42\x0c\xf8\x36\xd7\x43\x7d", 16, GRND_INSECURE) = 16
    16.183344 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/disk/by-diskseq/19565", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x10), ...}, 0) = 0
     0.000389 newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_SD_MMC_MS_PRO_20120926571200000-0:0", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x10), ...}, 0) = 0
```

But I do not know why `fstatat("/dev/disk/by-diskseq/19565")` would take a super long time.

This system has just one disk. According to `smartctl -a /dev/sda`, there are no errors,

```
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       47363
SMART Error Log Version: 0
No Errors Logged
```

That's about 5.5 years of uptime

EDIT2:

Someone asked about the /dev/disk/by-diskseq symlinks. I had just assumed they would point at /dev/sda, but that is not the case.

```
0 % ls -alhi /dev/disk/by-diskseq/
159385 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct  6 11:45 39685 -> ../../sdb
```

The symlink name (39685) seems to increment by 1 every ~minute or so. And apparently there's an `sdb` that I didn't know about.

```
0 % lsblk -ap
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk
├─/dev/sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
└─/dev/sda2   8:2    0 111.3G  0 part /
/dev/sdb      8:16   1     0B  0 disk

0 % fdisk -l /dev/sdb
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

Ahh, looks like it's the USB device? But there is nothing plugged into the USB slots.

```
% udevadm info /dev/sdb
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
M: sdb
U: block
T: disk
D: b 8:16
N: sdb
L: 0
S: disk/by-diskseq/39699
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
S: disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_SD_MMC_MS_PRO_20120926571200000-0:0
Q: 39699
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5.1/1-5.1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: DISKSEQ=39699
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=16
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4178478
E: ID_VENDOR=Generic-
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic-
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0bda
E: ID_MODEL=SD_MMC_MS_PRO
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=SD\x2fMMC\x2fMS\x20PRO\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0153
E: ID_REVISION=1.00
E: ID_SERIAL=Generic-_SD_MMC_MS_PRO_20120926571200000-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=20120926571200000
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=ums-realtek
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-diskseq/39699 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Generic-_SD_MMC_MS_PRO_20120926571200000-0:0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:
```

EDIT3

Nothing has any `sdb` files open, or `diskbyseq` links.

```
% lsof | grep sdb
# nothing
% lsof | grep diskseq
# nothing
```

System has been up for 13 days

```
% uptime
 09:55:33 up 13 days, 22:36,  1 user,  load average: 2.13, 2.08, 2.03
```

Comment: `Connection timed out` seems to be an interesting error.  Does this machine resolve user information by connecting to a network service like LDAP or Kerberos?

Comment: brk() calls are near instant. You've got a different issue. `strace` has options to print timing info, you could use them.

Comment: No LDAP or Kerberos. I'll try to get timings with strace.

Comment: But what device is /dev/disk/by-diskseq/19565?

Comment: Good question. Added some info about it to the question.

Comment: I guess some usb drive was time ago there and maybe it still has opened files. What lsof says about opened files in sdb and this link? When you reboot host last time? What mount says? Or there was something related to user environment on this device. Something related to systemd user units maybe https://nts.strzibny.name/systemd-user-services/

Comment: Added info about open files. Nothing has been plugged into the usb sockets in the last 13 days since the device was rebooted. I used a usb thumb drive when I installed the OS on the device, that's going to be 2 years ago or more.

Comment: Next step - check all systemd services that may touch  /dev/disk/by-diskseq

Comment: 0bda:0153 is an SDcard card reader, probably built-in to your machine and not fully supported. Try `rmmod` on the `ums-realtek` driver, and blacklisting it.